# Why breaks 'console.log' inside a stateless function expression?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, components

I'm sure it is just a syntax thing. How can I `console.log` inside a stateless function expression?

```
const Layer = (props) => (
  console.log(props); //breaks
)
```

Comment: please correct conosle!

Answer (score 11):

There's no need to change the structure of the component to use curly braces and adding a return.  You can do:

```
const Layer = (props) => console.log(props) || (
  ...whatever component does
);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
const StatelessComponent = props => {
   console.log(props);
   return (
      <div>{props.whatever}</div>
   )
}
```

Keep in mind that in a functional components there is **no** render method as is. 
Your JSX should be written in the return section of a function. That's not the react specific case. That's the behaviour of the arrow function itself.
Good luck coding :)

Answer (score 5):

It breaks because you're implicitly returning the result of the `console.log` call which is undefined, but you should be returning a valid react component

Add the curly brackets and return explicitly the component:

```
const Layer = (props) => { 
  console.log(props);
  return <div/> //return a valid React component
};
```

Comment: what's a template?

Comment: a valid jsx content

Comment: I think you mean to say a React Component. :)

Comment: console.log(props);
            <div className="layer" /> //this breaks

Comment: where is your `return` statement? as it is, it returns `undefined` which still breaks. also, notice the addition of `{ }` for the function body, plain `=> ` returns immediate statement so you can have `=> <div />` but you need `=> { console.log(props); return <div />` }`

Comment: exactly i just commented out the return but it must be there with a valid jsx content e.g.  <div></div>